# Verify If New Record Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table created to hold all my client data. The data is all entered in via form. When a new record is created (new client added) I also need to create an opening transaction balance on a separate table. So what is the best way to...

1) Identify that a new record has been create

2) Subsequently a new opening transaction record needs to be created?

I'm having a hard time getting my head wrapped around a process flow to accomplish this. Any thoughts or insights would be greatly appreciated. I am open to VBA or macro builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Before- or AfterInsert event of the form.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to get started.  I hadn't used these events before, but with them I was able to create what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a start.  In the design view of your client table, click the "Create Data Macros" button and select "after insert".  From there choose "Create Record" and select your transaction table.

Comment: All the data is being entered in on a form.  Can I still do what you suggested?

Comment: Yes, where the data is being entered does not mater, but it looks like you found a solution.